# Should I drop variable highly correlated with independent variable? (Causal inference)

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, bias, causality

I estimate OLS:

> Y = c + b1*x1 + ....+ bn*xn +err
>
> corr (Y, x1) = 0.8, Corr(x1,err)>0

Should  I drop variable x1? What kind of biases would I have in both cases: with and without x1.

Comment: Why would you want to drop a variable that would appear to have a lot of explanatory power in your regression equation?

Comment: I am worry in unbiased estimation of x2 - xN.  I am not interested in the prediction of Y.  I have some doubt, so I ask.

Comment: Then why is $y$ your target variable?

Comment: I am interested in causal effect of x2..xN on Y

Comment: How do you know x1 is correlated with the error term? Please give more context, tell us what your variables represent!

Comment: So here is endogeneity  $E[x1err]!=0$ .